# XPrivacy - explanation of restriction settings

Tags: settings, xprivacy

Maybe it's me but I don't understand XPrivacy's per-permission-settings.
The legend sais

- first check box: restrict category or function
- second check box: restrict on demand
- first check box is default value
- `■`: stands for "partly restricted"
- `?`: restrictions will be asked

But what does `✔` (checked) mean? Fully restricted? And what are the meanings of the combinations?

And what is the "default" case for?

Can you explain the following combinations:

`[ ] [ ]`  (no restrictions (the only one I truly understand :)))

`[ ] [?]`  (?? default: no restrictions but ask otherwise?)

`[ ] [✔]`  (?? default: no restrictions but full restrictions otherwise?)

`[ ] [■]`  (?? default: no restrictions but partly restricted otherwise?)

`[■] [ ]`  (?? default: partly restricted)

`[■] [■]`  (?? partly on demand, default is partly?)

`[✔] [ ]`  (?? default: fully restricted?)

`[✔] [?]`  (?? always restrict but ask otherwise??)

Which ones are missing?

Why isn't there a combination like `[■] [?]` or `[✔] [✔]`?

Please help me out..

Answer (score 3):

According to the README file of XPrivacy that can be found [here](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy/blob/master/README.md):

> The tri-state check box works this way:
>
> unchecked = no items in the category are restricted
>
> solid square =
> some items in the category are restricted
>
> check mark = all items in
> the category are restricted
>
> Note: By default, categories and functions
> are filtered by permission, so you may not see all of them. The check
> box state is independent of this.